# В chrome не отображается, а в Mozilla почему-то да

Tags: php, google-chrome

Добрый день! Столкнулась с тем, что такая строчка

```
<p><?php echo $str_index;?>   </p>
```

не отображается в chrome. А в Mozilla все нормально. Переустановила chrome. Все равно не отображается. Может кто-то знает в чем может быть дело?
    
         $str_index_echo = "Вы зашли как представитель магазина \"".$_SESSION['user']."\"";
?>

Comment: Было бы уместным прикрепить изображение на котором видно как должно быть, ибо непонятно вы говорите о пустой строке разделяющая текст или это нам ничего не видно

Comment: <p>  <?php echo $ str; ?><p/>

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, [MCVE](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - минимальный пример, который мы можем запустить и самостоятельно убедиться, что в одном браузере видно, а в другом не видно. Также стоит включить информацию о том, надо ли при заходе на этот php-скрипт передавать ему какие-то параметры в запросе. Эту информацию следует добавить прямо в вопрос - кнопка "править" находится под тэгами, слева от вашего имени.

Comment: @Masha а что отображается в `Mozilla` ?

Comment: у меня смешаный код. В php вставлен html а в html ставлен php.

Comment: тут по правилам такое нельзя опубликовывать?э

Comment: только по отдельности?

Comment: просто этот p создается по условию...и в него записывается переменная из php

Comment: в мозиле все появляется как надо.

Comment: и во всех остальных браузерах тоже.

Comment: переустановила хром...но та же картина. в отладчике все нормально видно. а на экране все есть кроме отображения этого p

Comment: Проблема решилась перестановкой в другое место html. на div ниже. Теперь все браузеры отображают. Но я так и не поняла, почему в тот раз все отображали а хром нет. Чем ему не нравилось то старое место в html. И часто ли такое происходит, а то я новичок , а тут такие вещи происходят...